Not able to access redis insight in browser
i am using redis stack as a docker image. the redis is connecting to the cli but the redis insight is not opening on the browser.
As far as i've searched the internet the solution for this is to change the port number in the docker run command. I've also tried that but still its not working.

You'll need to share the docker commands or docker compose files you're using to run the container for anyone to be able to offer suggestions.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I have this docker-compose and I am not able to access the redis-insight
version: '3.8'

services:
  redis-stack:
    image: redis/redis-stack:latest
    container_name: redis_stack
    ports:
      - "1234:6379"
      - "8001:8001"
    volumes:
      - ./.cache_redis_data:/data
      - ./redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf
    command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    networks:
      - cache_network

networks:
  cache_network:
    driver: bridge

and If I remove the
command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
line , it worked but I want the redis.conf to run for persistent data

Solution: Found the solution for the issue. After checking the entrypoint.sh from the redis-stack image, I discovered that it needs a redis-stack.conf file in the root directory to run correctly. So, I just needed to copy the redis-stack.conf to the correct path based on the entrypoint.sh from the redis-stack image.
In this case:
volumes:

./.cache_redis_data:/data
./redis.conf:/redis-stack.conf
This works!!
Thanks!!


I came across the same problem. I am also using the redis-stack as a docker image. I can connect to Redis via redis-cli but unfortunately Redis Insight cannot be accessed, nor on port 8001 or 5540 as documentation tells. I found a solution, that worked for me:
My docker compose was like this:
version: "3" services: redis: image: redis/redis-stack:latest container_name: redis hostname: redis restart: unless-stopped mem_limit: 1g cpu_shares: 1024 command: ["redis-server", "/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"] healthcheck: test: ["CMD-SHELL", "redis-cli ping || exit 1"] network_mode: host volumes: - redis_data:/data - /PWD/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf volumes: redis_data:
The problem was in the command itself building the container with the instruction to (only) start the redis-server and not the entire redis-stack. The default command is to start the entire stack, including Insight. Therefore, the command can be omitted. The working docker compose looks like this. The configuration as prescribed in the redis.conf file is included in the boot of the container. No need to separately include it in the command.
version: "3" services: redis: image: redis/redis-stack:latest container_name: redis hostname: redis restart: unless-stopped mem_limit: 1g cpu_shares: 1024 healthcheck: test: ["CMD-SHELL", "redis-cli ping || exit 1"] network_mode: host volumes: - redis_data:/data - /PWD/redis/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf volumes: redis_data:
